# Angular Clickable list

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

can anyone please help me out on how to go to next form when you click on a list item using angular js ? using an example like I have a list of addresses in one form , when i click on any address  , it should redirect to next page showing the directions . thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You need to post some code to at least give us some direction on what you're doing. You could use an ng-click, you could have `<a>` tags in your list items with the path.

Comment: I am actually working on appery.io tool , thats the reason I was not able to post the code because its totally different to work on , Im new to this tool . its my bad that I have asked a question without thinking . thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at ngRoute at w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

With ngRoute you can define specific routes in your application that link to a html file that you assigned. Although you really should read the whole article because it actually is pretty self explanatory and a little more complex then just the code below this example should give you an indication of how it works.

**After you did this you can then link a specific field or row in your list to a url that you defined.**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't just link something in your answer, post the relevant piece along with it.

Comment: I thought this was pretty self explanitory. Still, I'll edit my original answer.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot Marc ! I am actually working on appery.io tool , thats the reason I was not able to post the code because its totally different to work on , Im new to this tool . its my bad that I have asked a question without thinking . thanks for the reply !